TinyMCE's top toolbar conflicts with my Modal/Lightbox
I am having some issues with the TinyMCE editor, The menu bar seems to appear over the top of my Modal. I can not seem to put the menu bar behind the modal.

If I scroll the screen up and down, the menu bar moves over the top of the modal, which it is not meant to do. What would be the right way to go about correcting this issue. Thanks

Look at the z-index property : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Thanks, I changed the z-index from a 1 to a 2, and it seems to have worked
